# async await Promise usage blocks forever on await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

The event handler for websocket connection (`wss.on`) is called that calls an async function `sendInitialState()`. There I call an async function (`getMetadata()`) that returns a Promise in which I do some async stuff. I resolve the promise,  `resolve(res)` is called, but **the program still blocks on await**, that is `console.log(metadata)` is never called.

```
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {

    sendInitialState();
});

const sendInitialState = async (ws) => {

    console.log('Sending initial state!');
    const metadata = await getMetadata();
    console.log('metadata:', metadata);
};

const getMetadata = async () => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
            if (err) {reject(err);}
            else {
              db.collection("meta").findOne({type: 'a'}, (err, res) => {
                if (err) reject(err);
                else {
                    db.close();
                    console.log('Metadata found: ', res);
                    resolve(res);
                }

              });
            }
        }); 
    });

}
```

What is the reason my program blocks?

(I tried adding async before outer `(ws) =>`, but outcome is the same)

Comment: For starters, `if (err) throw err` is wrong and should be `if (err) return reject(err);` in both places you have it.  For future reference, `if (err) throw err` should pretty much NEVER be in your code, ever.  I've never encountered a circumstance where that is correct error handling.  And, then you need to put a `try/catch` around your `await` so you can catch any errors that might happen.  Error handling is not to be ignored here and is probably the first thing you should look at when things are not working as expected.

Comment: Also, it should be `console.log('metadata:', blockchainMetadata);`.  You're referring to the wrong variable in your log statement.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the variable (was editing code prior to posting). Regarding return reject(err), shouldn't it be just reject(err) without return?

Comment: Well, you don't exactly what to execute all the other statements after calling the `reject()` so you should use some flow of control to separate out the error path from the non-error path.  You can use `if/else` or `return`.  Remember, `reject()` is not like `throw`.  It's just a function call so code in that block keeps on executing after you call `reject()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Promises automatically convert any thrown errors to a rejected Promise that can be caught in a `catch()`. Why is `throw` in this case invalid, isn't this just a performance thing since there isn't optimization around `throw`?

Comment: @peteb - That code is not inside a promise callback.  It's inside a database async callback.  There's no auto-conversion to reject there.

Comment: Isn't it that reject() call automatically stops promise execution.

Comment: No.  `reject()` is JUST an ordinary function call.  Your function keeps executing the rest of the code in the block.  You should use regular flow control to separate out the code you want to execute in the error path from the non-error path.  Regular Javascript programming techniques.

Comment: `reject()` does latch the state of the promise to `rejected` so it can never be changed again, but does not stop the rest of the function block from executing.

Comment: @jfriend00 but its inside a `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { throw new Error() })`. It should propagate out no? `sendInitialState()` just needs a `try/catch` inside of it and this would work and wait no?

Comment: @peteb - No.  Regular exceptions don't propagate through plain async callbacks like you are thinking.  This is the whole reason for using promises at the lowest level (which this code is not doing).  If you promisfy at the lowest level and ONLY right code using promises, then all exceptions will be caught by the promise infrastructure and propagate as rejected promises.  But, this code uses regular callbacks inside and they don't have that feature.  You make yourself a little test program in jsFiddle to try it out.

Comment: @jfriend00 ah gotcha, wrapping a traditional callback doesn't follow the same error channel, it needs to be a Promise from the original `throw`. Hence needing the `reject()` for using the correct error channel. Makes more sense now.

Comment: But all this is just a side note. The promise is returned in the middle function after await keyword. It gets resolved ("Metadata found" is logged), but the await still blocks.

Comment: @croraf `await` will block the remaining bits of a function from occurring until the value awaited has returned, thats how the code looks synchronous. If you want to log metadata, regardless of the await, then you should move that `console.log()` outside the `async` function so it can continue regardless of the result of `sendInitialState()`. However, based on your code, your metadata is retrieved asynchronously so you can't print it before you have it...

Comment: FFS I think I have a typo in the original code :(. No I want to log only when await is finished. The above code is now correct, I found a typo in the original code. Thanks guys for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

While `reject()'ing` the promise instead of a throw solved it for you, your code style can be improved:

- When converting a callback to a promise, there's no need to declare the function as async: it would just wrap into another promise;
- It is probably better to declare functions instead of assigning a function expression to a const;
- To reduce indentation, the pattern would be `if (err) { return reject(err); }`: this removes the need for an else clause;
- We probably want to reuse promise-based functions, so extracting common logic leads to more readable code;

The OP was more about promises than async/await, so this is a rewritten version with smaller functions, shallow indentation and using more of async/await.

```js
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  sendInitialState();
});

async function sendInitialState(ws) {
  console.log('Sending initial state!');
  const metadata = await getMetadata();
  console.log('metadata:', metadata);
}

function connect(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(db);
    });
  });
}

function findOne(db, collectionName, object) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.collection(collectionName).findOne(object, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      console.log('Metadata found: ', res);
      resolve(res);
    });
  });
}

async function getMetadata() {
  const db = await connect(url);
  const res = await findOne(db, 'meta', {
    type: 'a'
  });
  db.close();
  console.log('Metadata found: ', res);
  return res;
}
```